# First time AWS user

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

probably stupid question but.. as the title says I'm completely new with AWS. I've been given some credentials.

```
BUCKET_NAME
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
Location : s3://xxx
Allowed permisions : xxx
```

What do I have to do to access the bucket? Do I have to create an AWS account or am I good just with those creds by hitting some API?

Comment: Access....how? Is this actually a question about programming? I don't see any code...

Comment: @JaredSmith Well I guess it's a bit too generic question for any code. It is a question leading to programming.

Comment: You don't need an AWS account.
If you install the credentials as defined by your operating system, and install the aws-cli utility, you can run `aws s3 ls s3://xxx` to see the contents, if you have permission.  That's an easy first test.  Then code you write against the API should work too.

Comment: @BrentBradburn ooh, lovely. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your not adverse to installing libraries, [Boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) is a good choice. To use it, you do need an AWS user. This [guide](https://realpython.com/python-boto3-aws-s3/) has a good explanation on how to set up an account and access AWS resources using Boto3.

If you prefer official AWS doc, look [here](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/).

Comment: No worries. Good luck!